# Symfony vichUploader tmp file does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

**The error** is the following:

> The file "C:\xampp\tmp\php5B9.tmp" does not exist
>       500 Internal Server Error - FileNotFoundException Stack Trace in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.php
>   at line 37

**I use Symfony 2.8, VichUploader 1.3.1, and YML entity config**

**My formType:**

```
            $builder
                ->add('name')

                ->add('frontImage', VichImageType::class, array(
                    'required' => false,
                ));
```

```
My config file:
<pre>
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        category_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/categories
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/categories
            namer:              vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
```

**My entity:**

```
    AppBundle\Entity\Category:
        type: entity
        table: category
        repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
        gedmo:
          soft_deleteable:
            field_name: deletedAt
            time_aware: false
          tree:
            type: nested
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                nullable: false
                unsigned: true
                id: true
                generator:
                    strategy: IDENTITY
        fields:
            name:
                type: string
                nullable: true
                length: 100
                fixed: false
                column: name
            type:
                type: ModelObjectType
                length: 20
                nullable: false
            visible:
                type: boolean
                nullable: true

            deletedAt:
              type: datetime
              nullable: true

            frontImageName:
              type: string
              length: 255
              nullable: true

            deviceAlertThreshold:
              type: integer
              nullable: true
              unsigned: true

            lft:
              type: integer
              nullable: true
              gedmo:
                - treeLeft

            rgt:
              type: integer
              nullable: true
              gedmo:
                - treeRight

            lvl:
              type: integer
              nullable: true
              gedmo:
                - treeLevel

        oneToMany:
            categoryParameter:
                targetEntity: CategoryParameter
                mappedBy: category
                cascade: [all]
                orphanRemoval: true
            children:
                targetEntity: Category
                mappedBy: parent
                cascade: [remove]
                orderBy:
                  lft: ASC
            devices:
                targetEntity: Device
                mappedBy: category

        manyToOne:
            root:
              targetEntity: Category
              joinColumn:
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: CASCADE
              gedmo:
                - treeRoot
            parent:
              targetEntity: Category
              inversedBy: children
              joinColumn:
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: CASCADE
              gedmo:
                - treeParent

        lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Config in the resources/config/vich_uploader:**

```
    AppBundle\Entity\Category:
        frontImage:
            mapping: category_image
            filename_property: frontImageName
```

HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. The problem was in the base controller, I used something like this:

```
Request::createFromGlobals()
```

and everything seems to work fine

Comment: I mean with the Request::createFromGlobals(); it wasnt working. Once deleted this line - works fine.